# Ошибка Index out of range в QVector

Tags: c++, qt

`pointsOfGrid` заполняются нормально, не мусором, `maxRadius` - аналогично. Ошибка возникает при попытке установить `QCPCurveData` ума не приложу что делать...

В .h объявлены

```
QVector<QCPCurve *> rounds;
QMap<int, QVector<QCPCurveData>> pointsOfGrid;
QSet<int> allRadius;
```

В .cpp

```
//значение radius снимается со спинбокса
if (!allRadius.contains (radius)) { 
    allRadius.insert (radius); 
}

auto maxRadius = allRadius.end() - 1;
for (int j = 0; j < *maxRadius; j++) {

    if (!pointsOfGrid.contains(j)) {        
        QVector <QCPCurveData> temp(POINTS_FOR_GRID);

        for (int i = 0; i < POINTS_FOR_GRID; i++) {        
            double theta = (i / 180.0) * M_PI;
            temp[i]=QCPCurveData (i, j * qCos (1 * theta), j * qSin (1 * theta));
        }                       
        pointsOfGrid.insert (j, temp);
    }
}

while (rounds.size()>*maxRadius) {
    rounds.removeLast();
}

rounds.squeeze();      
for (int i = 0; i < *maxRadius; i++) {    
    if(rounds.isEmpty() || !rounds[i]) {    
        rounds[i] = new QCPCurve (widget->xAxis, widget->yAxis);
        rounds[i]->data()->set(pointsOfGrid[i]);//в этой строчке вылетает 
        //с QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range"
        rounds[i]->setPen(penForGrid);
    }
}
```

Должно рисовать окружности  в полярных координатах, дополнительно использую библиотеку QCustomPlot

Comment: *"как указачель на максимальный элемент"* - не как указатель на максимальный индекс, а именно как на *элемент*?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что проблема именно в инициализации `r`. Или в `rounds`. Как минимум, `r` должно быть не указателем на максимальный элемент, а указателем на размер массива, еще лучше вообще обойтись без указателя. Ну и в выражении `1 * theta` вероятно происходит не то, что вы хотите. Возможно, нужно использовать `1.0 * theta`?

Comment: @Ariox, @Harry, с `r` все в порядке, отладчик показывает правильные значения, но на всякий случай

`QSet<int> allRadius;`
`auto maxRadius = allRadius.end() - 1;`

попытки задать количество значений в `rounds` тоже не помогли, компилятор сразу начинает ругаться

Comment: А где участок кода, где Вы указываете размер вектора `rounds`? Если Вы не задаете размер (а в представленном коде получается, что Ваш вектор пустой и, соответственно, выполняется эта часть условия: `if(rounds.isEmpty()..` ), то тогда и получаете вполне обоснованно исключение "index out of range".

Comment: @Vladimir, а как указать размер? Мне казалось что я добавляю в вектор как раз строкой `rounds[i] = new QCPCurve`, а так `append` вызвал ошибку на уровне синаксиса, как и подобное `QVector<QCPCurve *> rounds(10);`

Comment: Насколько я понимаю (я основываюсь на std::vector, но QVector же с него писали?) последняя строчка в комментарии не должна вызывать ошибку. В его конструктор можно передавать размер, судя по документации на Qt. Вероятно, этого размера было недостаточно. У Вас же необходимый размер вектора определяется как `*maxRadius`? (вообще, по-моему, это очень неудачное название для размера массива).. Чтобы позже изменить размер (если на момент задания Вам нужный размер неизвестен), можно использовать метод вектора `resize()`. Например, его можно поставить в то место, где у Вас цикл `while`...

Comment: @Vladimir, спасибо `resize()` помог